# Get the variable via CURL

Tags: php, html, api, curl

Through API guidance I am trying to get these parameters. But what php code do I have to write to actually get the result as a variable $result?

CURL is installed at the server level. Sorry I'm a bit lost. Thanks!

`curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"start_date":"2016-08-02","end_date":"2016-08-03", "columns":["paid_impressions","revenue"]}' 'http://udmserve.com/udm/radalytics_api.cpx?action=report&api_key=xxxx'`

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a free code conversion service. If you download a tool such as "postman", there is a feature there which will build the PHP code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works. You'll need to work amend it to store your api key though

```
<?php

//Initiate a curl request
$ch = curl_init();

//This is your API key
$apiKey = "xxxx";

//These are your postFields
$postFields = array(
        "start_date" => "2016-08-02",
        "end_date"   => "2016-08-03",
        "columns"    => array(
                "paid_impressions",
                "revenue"
            )
    );

//Setup the curl options using variables in place of your postFields and apiKey
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://udmserve.com/udm/radalytics_api.cpx?action=report&api_key=" . $apiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $postFields ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set up the request headers
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//Make the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//If there was an error, display error code
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

//Delete the curl object
curl_close ($ch);

//Show the result
echo $result;

//Or, print as array
echo '<pre>'. print_r( json_decode($result), 1 ) .'</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Harvey! But how do I extract from all this and make a list to show only date and revenue from the array. Like a list: 2018-10-27 -  XX USD, 2018-10-28 - XX USD, and so on.. At the moment the output looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ac24io15gc0oab3/output.txt

Comment: Thanks, I see now that when I don't print as array it show a lot less, only the top part of the 'output.txt' (http://dropbox.com/s/ac24io15gc0oab3/output.txt), but how do I make this array into a list showing like: 2018-10-27 - XX USD, 2018-10-28 - XX USD, Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: This is the output without the print array part , Thanks!! https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9wpicot4990xkb/output2.txt

Comment: it has now been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083698/listing-information-from-an-array-php#53083914