# Listing information from an Array (php)

Tags: php, html, arrays, curl

I have connected to an API via CURL and I get what is below returned to me.

I'm a bit lost. But how would I with the help of PHP extract and display information so it looks like:

2018-10-26 - 28.46 USD

2018-10-27 - 25.70 USD

2018-10-28 - 29.07 USD

Thank you so much for help! /Marcus

`{"options":{"ranking_metric":"paid_impressions","time_interval":"day","report_type":"time","filters":{"pid":"2759"},"data_source":"detailed","format":"json","end_date":"2018-10-28 23:59","columns":["paid_impressions","revenue"],"time_zone":"UTC","start_date":"2018-10-26 00:00"},"sql":"\n SELECT\n '',\n FIRST(CONCAT('',STRING(''))) AS _combined_val,\n SUM(if(media_tbl.mtid = 3, imps, 0)) as paid_impressions,SUM(pub_rev) as revenue,\n SUM(paid_impressions) OVER(PARTITION BY _combined_val) ranking_col,\n DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ranking_col DESC) rank,\n STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp +(7*1000*1000*60*60)),'%F %R') as timestamp\n FROM\n\n (SELECT * from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(counts.hourly_custom_cust1_, DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2018-10-26 00:00'),-(7),'HOUR'), DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2018-10-28 23:59'),7,'HOUR'))) as tbl\n\n LEFT JOIN (select sid as _sid, pid FROM counts.udm_synchronize_table_site_tbl) as site_tbl\n ON tbl.sid = site_tbl._sid\n\n LEFT JOIN (select mid as _mid, aid, tid, mtid FROM counts.udm_synchronize_table_media_tbl) as media_tbl\n ON tbl.mid = media_tbl._mid\n\n WHERE 1=1 AND site_tbl.pid IN (2759) AND timestamp >= DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2018-10-26 00:00'),-(7),'HOUR') AND timestamp <= DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2018-10-28 23:59'),-(7),'HOUR')\n GROUP BY timestamp,\n ORDER BY timestamp,rank,","api_url":"http://udmserve.com/udm/radalytics_api.cpx?action=report&api_key=xxxx&api_key=xxxx","time":1540989662,"rows":[{"paid_impressions":"18136","timestamp":"2018-10-26 00:00","_combined_val":"","ranking_col":"49046","revenue":"28.461629999999985","rank":"1","f0_":""},{"paid_impressions":"14432","timestamp":"2018-10-27 00:00","_combined_val":"","ranking_col":"49046","revenue":"25.707970000000017","rank":"1","f0_":""},{"paid_impressions":"16478","timestamp":"2018-10-28 00:00","_combined_val":"","ranking_col":"49046","revenue":"29.07676000000002","rank":"1","f0_":""}]}`

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Where do those values come from? Where does "USD" come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `json_decode()` curl response and apply `foreach()` to get desired result

```
$array = json_decode($curl_response,true);
foreach($array['rows'] as $arr){
  echo explode(' ',$arr['timestamp'])[0].'-'.number_format((float)$arr['revenue'], 2, '.', '').' USD'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/eUavL

Comment: Thank you so much! This is fantastic and it works great :)

Comment: Just one more question. How could I easily list the total below it all? Thanks!!